# Vertical size of post "window" too short

Tags: bug, ios-app, mathjax

It appears the calculation of the vertical space used for a post is incorrect in some situations.  Here's one example:

> [image]

You can see the bottom of the post is cut off.  I can "scroll" the post by selecting a word and then extending the selection downwards, as in:

> [image]

But then of course the top is cut off.  I suspect this has to do with math formatting.

- App Version: 1.5.3.5
- Device: iPad mini 2G (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 9.3.4 (Build 13G35)